# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've a spring boot project that I can run successfully from within IntelliJ, but when I package an executable jar I can no longer run it. Here is the stack trace of the exception:

```
18:13:55.254 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@b3d7190: startup date [Wed Sep 07 18:13:55 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
18:13:55.403 [main] WARN  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [el.dorado.App]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
18:13:55.414 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [el.dorado.App]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:489)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at dz.lab.jpmtask.App.main(App.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:276)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:481)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

My configuration is something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppConfig {
  ... some beans
}
```

I've added `META-INF/spring.factories` under the project resources folder as described in [43.2 Locating auto-configuration candidates](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) as follows But this didn't fix the problem:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
el.dorado.AppConfig
```

Here is the project `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>el.dorado</groupId>
  <artifactId>ElDorado</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ElDorado</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
     <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>el.dorado.App</mainClass>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--<version>0.7.8-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on your *entry point* configuration class in order for Boot to scan this `AppConfig` in the first place.

Comment: Can you share the SpringBootApplication class and the pom.xml as well

Comment: That's a weird setup. For one you shouldn't put `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on an auto-configuration class. Please review the doc you've referenced. Second, it looks like you're trying to run your app without `spring-boot-autoconfigure` on the classpath. There are no `spring.factories` found so your build does not package it properly. Please share a project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I thought I've to add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` somewhere for spring-boot to configure other beans (e.g. for JPA). I've updated the question with the project `pom.xml`. Also, when I inspect the generated jar with `jar tf jar-file` I actually see that `META-INF/spring.factories` exists so I guess the build is properly packaged!

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do but it looks like you don't need an auto-configuration at all. Why are you creating a `META-INF/spring.factories` in the first place?

Comment: because the exception says to make sure the file exists, I thought I can fix the problem by adding it.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I've the same exception when I remove the file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just figure it out, I should have been using [Spring Boot maven plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) instead. Now the build section of my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <mainClass>dz.lab.jpmtask.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!--<version>0.7.8-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-site</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I build the project with `mvn clean package` and then `java -jar target/myproject.jar` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have forgotten to use Annotation in your AppConfig.

Add following three annotations to your `AppConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("Scan_Package_Name") 
public class AppConfig {
  ... some beans
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

1. Delete the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`
2. Config spring transformers in shade plugin please refer to [spring parent pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/37bef961ea52e03b48e08c9bc865acb69400621d/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml#L171-L221)

Answer (score 0):

I've also gotten the

> Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [...]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class ...

error due to a typo in my `spring.factories` file. In this case the root exception was

> class path resource [...] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

This is an important spot to check since it can't be validated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from
`mvn clean compile assembly:single`
to
`mvn clean package`
and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. If you are also using tomcat, cleaning it did the trick for me.

[image]