# spring-boot-maven-plugin create jar with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

My project is running fine in eclipse. I was using the following plugin to build my jar with dependencies.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.project.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

On running the jar, I got the following error.

```
2017-07-17 15:21:06.825 ERROR 17587 --- [           
main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : 
Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.project.App]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. 
If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375016/failed-to-process-import-candidates-for-configuration-class) solution to use spring-boot-maven-plugin and modified my code as shown below.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <mainClass>com.project.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The error was fixed. However, the jar created through this process does not contain dependencies. Is it possible to build jar with dependencies using spring-boot-maven-plugin? Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: That jar should contain the dependencies, if not you are doing something really wrong.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm having the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it and run with `mvn clean package` evething will be okay.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>false</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```