# How does Spring load the classpath?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classpath

I have a Spring Boot Web application XX, which in turn is using a library, YY,  built using Spring. I have declared YY library details in XX's POM.

In my YY library I have a Cinfig class annotated with following :

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource({ "classpath:abc.properties" })
    class YYLibraryConfig {
```

I have declared abc.properties in src/main/resources of YY library. Now when I am running Spring Boot application XX , I am getting the following error :

```
InvocationTargetException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.sample.YYLibraryConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'abc.properties' in string value "classpath:${abc.properties}"
```

Comment: Can you post your application.properties and Application.java

Comment: How are you building your application ? As an executable jar ? Are you using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin to create this ? If not you need to.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792031/springboot-making-jar-files-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375016/failed-to-process-import-candidates-for-configuration-class

Comment: Try to remove "**{**" and "**}**", use this one: `@PropertySource("classpath:abc.properties")`.